# Load bar with Akka streaming

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Is it possible to have some kind of loading bar with Akka streaming?
I'm looking for something that may give the advancement state of a source.

```
Source via loadingBar(expectedElment) via someThingElse to Sink
```

where `expectedElement` is the number of elements that should pass through when "100%" is achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to monitor the progress from outside the stream then I recommend using an [`Agent`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/agents.html).  The Agent will store the running count:

```
import akka.agent.Agent
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow

def runningCountFlow[T](agent : Agent[Float]) = Flow[T].map { val =>
  agent send (_ + 1.0f)
  val
}
```

You can then monitor the agent outside of the stream:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val expectedCount = 42.toFloat
val countAgent = Agent(0.0f)

type DataType = ???

val stream = 
  Source via runningCountFlow[DataType](countAgent) via someThingElse runWith Sink

Thread.sleep(5000) //let the stream run for a while

val percentComplete = countAgent.get / expectedCount

println(s"stream is $percentComplete complete")
```

Comment: The agent resolve the concurrent problem (I hope)
But maybe something like this would be better
```
def runningCountFlow[T](agent : Agent[Float],show:Interval) = Flow[T].map { val =>
  agent send (_ + 1.0f)
  if(agent.get % interval) {
    println(s"stream is $percentComplete complete")
  }
  val
} 
```

Comment: Agents were deprecated in Akka 2.6. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/project/migration-guide-2.5.x-2.6.x.html#removed-features-that-were-deprecated